# Flutter: RangeError (index) when building a Row inside a listView

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, dart, error-handling

I have been attempting to solve this bug for hours and just can't seem to fix it. My app goes from a quick loading screen, to a home screen, but inbetween, the screen flashes red for a second with the following error:

> The following RangeError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, state: _HomeScreenState#9b318):
> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

I've managed to isolate it inside my code, it's the bottom container I have displaying forecast information.

```
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 30),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFF2F3148),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: selectedWeather(),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

the SelectedWeather method is this:

```
 ///Returns the hourly or daily weather forecast based on which tab is selected.
  ///selectedIndex is 0 by default, when "This Week" is selected, it becomes 1, returning
  ///the daily weather forecast. Used as a child of the final Row in build().
  List<Widget> selectedWeather() {
    if (selectedIndex == 0) {
      return [
        hourlyWeather[0],
        hourlyWeather[1],
        hourlyWeather[2],
        hourlyWeather[3],
        hourlyWeather[4],
        hourlyWeather[5],
        hourlyWeather[6],
        hourlyWeather[7],
        hourlyWeather[8],
        hourlyWeather[9],
        hourlyWeather[10],
        hourlyWeather[11],
      ];
    } else if (selectedIndex == 1) {
      return [
        dailyWeather[0],
        dailyWeather[1],
        dailyWeather[2],
        dailyWeather[3],
        dailyWeather[4],
        dailyWeather[5],
        dailyWeather[6],
      ];
    } else {
      return [OvalWeather("null", 0, "null")];
    }
  }
```

All this code does is return the corresponding forecast information based on what a user taps. I suspect that this is causing the issue, as in my stack trace:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomeScreen file:///E:/Projects/flutter/myapps/clear_skies/lib/screens/LoadingScreen.dart:37:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
#1      _HomeScreenState.**selectedWeather** (package:clear_skies/screens/HomeScreen.dart:356:22)
#2      _HomeScreenState.build (package:clear_skies/screens/HomeScreen.dart:521:41)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
```

I feel like the main problem is it's loading the UI without getting the information first. Of course, I can't make the build() widget asynchronous, but I've made a method updateUI() async, where it populates the lists used in selectedWeather(). I can't make selectedWeather() async, as the **Children** part of the Row within listView demands a list not a Future. The app loads and works perfectly, just a second or so after the screens are created but I can't deploy the app with this red screen popping up.

I've tried to populated the weather forecast lists in initState() but that crashes my app. Additionally, when I just comment out that part of code, another error appears which I believe to be caused by the same reason, populating things without first waiting on the info.

> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

Yet this error also disappears in a split second after the screen loads.

What should I do?

Comment: Try using `FutureBuilder` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Did you tried changing the cross axis alignment in Row with in container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you're trying to access elements of your lists `hourlyWeather` and `dailyWeather` while the lists are empty. You can just return an empty `Container` (or whatever else you want) when the lists are empty using an additional `if` clause.

```dart
List<Widget> selectedWeather() {
  if (hourlyWeather.isEmpty || dailyWeather.isEmpty) {
    return [Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator())];
  } else {
    if (selectedIndex == 0) {
      return [
        hourlyWeather[0],
        hourlyWeather[1],
        hourlyWeather[2],
        hourlyWeather[3],
        hourlyWeather[4],
        hourlyWeather[5],
        hourlyWeather[6],
        hourlyWeather[7],
        hourlyWeather[8],
        hourlyWeather[9],
        hourlyWeather[10],
        hourlyWeather[11],
      ];
    } else if (selectedIndex == 1) {
      return [
        dailyWeather[0],
        dailyWeather[1],
        dailyWeather[2],
        dailyWeather[3],
        dailyWeather[4],
        dailyWeather[5],
        dailyWeather[6],
      ];
    } else {
      return [OvalWeather("null", 0, "null")];
    }
  }
}
```